# SharePoint 2GB Max file upload experence

Tags: sharepoint, user-experience, maximum

We are running a Sharepoint WSS 3.0 Server with a full SQL 2005 version, on a single Windows 2003 Standard server. with 2GB RAM.

We have a file upload limit of 100MB.  I have been asked to look into increasing the file limit to the maximum that the SQL will allow.  (2GB)

I have read the papers and seen the notes on how to do it.  Such as the notes on the changes that needed to be done for the IIS and timeout,   That is all well and good and the theory is great, has anyone done this and what issues have they ran into?

What I would like to see and hear is had anyone done this.  What has their experiences been like for performance and user experience for the users, as well as the Server and the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. SharePoint recommends a file size limitation of 50MB, you are already at twice that. The reason is that, even though SQL can handle up to 2GB, it's very taxing on the SQL server and negatively affects performance.

You only want to store documents on SharePoint, not executables or other files. It's not designed to replace a standard file share, it's designed to enhance project collaboration and document management.

I think a good starting point is, what are they planning on storing up there that's so large?

Jes

Answer (score 0):

We have had experience with 100MB files and that is enough for me to advise you not to persue this.

A 2 GB file in Sharepoint is too large for any collaboration features to be usefule, so the main reason for SharePoint is gone.

It is possible to add the files to a custom database to get the benefits of backup and versioning.

The best idea is to put the file on a fileshare, back the files up from there. The SharePoint search can hit the fileshare if need be.

Just don't upload to the website.